# Is it possible to use #if 0 inside a multiline macro

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I want to implement something like below

```
#define MACRO_X \
    MACRO_1 \
    MACRO_2 \
#if condition
    MACRO_3 \
#endif
    MACRO_4 \
```

Comment: what happened when you tried to use it?

Comment: No, it's not possible.  The C Preprocessor is not a full-fledged programming language, and if you're trying to do fancy things with it (like this), it's usually a bad idea.  (Actually, multiline macros like your `MACRO_X` can be considered a bad idea even before you try to start embedding `#if`'s in them!)

Comment: @SteveSummit: Unfortunately, it's rather awkwardly just powerful enough to discourage the development of anything better.

Comment: The question is really WHAT you want to do. Macros might not be the correct answer. for examples there are also function templates

Comment: @PepijnKramer   I can think of very few cases in standard C++ for which macros are the correct answer - or, at the least, there is a viable alternative without using macros.   My list starts with include guards.    And I struggle to find a second case to list.

Comment: @CibiR Are you able to narrow down the question of whether you're actually programming in C or C++?  In C, the rule these days is, "Don't use the C Preprocessor much, and definitely not for anything complicated or cryptic or confusing".  But in C++, the rule is pretty much, "Don't use the C Preprocessor at all (except for `#include`)."

Comment: @Peter There are a few cases, I do sometimes use them. But they are usually not my first choice. And this looks like something that `if constexpr` might have a go at. But as long as I don't know what OP wants I can't tell.

Comment: There are no `multi-line` macros.  the `\` is an escape that removes the following character (newline) so that the macro becomes a single line as required by the pre-processor.  Since after _escape processing_ it is a single line, and for all pre-processor directives the `#` must be the first non-whitespace character in the line, the answer is no.

Comment: Note there is a big chance your problem can be solve in more elegant way by use of template. This requires more information what is your actual goal (why you needed this macros at all). Please [see this](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es31-dont-use-macros-for-constants-or-functions)

Answer (score 5):

You can't embed preprocessor directives into macros. Instead, do this:

```
#if condition
#define IF_COND(...) __VA_ARGS__
#else
#define IF_COND(...)
#endif
```

Then:

```
#define MACRO_X \
    MACRO_1 \
    MACRO_2 \
    IF_COND( \
        MACRO_3 \
    ) \
    MACRO_4 \
```